# How add location permission to service when it should work even application closed in android?

Tags: java, android, service, permissions, geolocation

I have some problem. I write an application which should write track using location. I give for this application permission to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. My Service implemented LocationListener, but when I check permission it always return me "false". Also this Service should work even application close. How can I fix this problem? How I cand give ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to my Service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for [runtime permissions.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

On the other hand, in new version of OS (Oreo and later), [requesting location in background services are limited.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html)